# How do I check whether audio file samples are clipped without playing the file?

Tags: linux, files, audio

I have a big MP3 audio file, about 170 MB, which I'd like to check for clipping. In details I need to increase the audio volume but I don't want to push the volume too high and clip audio samples. I tried audacity to check samples visually but it hangs before I can view anything and — and my machine has 12GB RAM!

I know `sox` provides a visual indications when audio samples are clipped but I need to play the file. So is there any command line tool that can tell me whether samples are clipped without having to play it at normal speed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**sox** doesn't need to play the file in order to gather statistics on it. Use `-n` to suppress sound output. Use the `stat` effect to find info on max levels:

```
$ sox mytest.mp3 -n stat
...
Maximum amplitude:     0.228743
Minimum amplitude:    -0.235424
...
Volume adjustment:        4.248
```

The above example file can have its volume increased by 4.2 to be normalised without clipping:

```
$ sox -v 4.24 mytest.mp3 norm.mp3
$ sox norm .mp3 -n stat 
...
Maximum amplitude:     0.921943
Minimum amplitude:    -0.951687
...
Volume adjustment:        1.051
```

Comment: Thanks @meuh, didn't know that. That's perfect. I had to increase the volume by at least 30db so get a sound close to normal listening conditions.